# Formula to always show four days past due date

Tags: excel-formula

I am looking for a formula in Excel that will always show 4 days from the original due date and is always in the future from today's date.

Let's assume in this example that today's date is 4/4/2018.  I would want the formula to let me know that I need to send a letter on the 6th.

```
Due date  Time To Send Letter
3/1/2018  4/6/2018
```

When we pass 4/6/2018, then the Time To Send Letter cell will then show 4/10/2018.

When we pass 4/10/2018, then the Time To Send Letter cell will then show 4/14/2018.

When we pass 4/14/2018, then the Time To Send Letter cell will then show 4/18/2018.

Comment: if today is `4/4/2018` would not 4 days from then be `4/8/2018`?

Comment: Your example seems contradictory, but in Excel you can literally take your date and say `4/4/2018 + 4,` which returns `4/8/2018`

Comment: I am having difficulty in my wording.  I guess it is every 4th day from the original due date, but only the next one coming up.

Comment: Can you give a couple more examples?

Comment: You literally just need to go `+ 4`, since 1 day = `1.0`.  So if your date was in cell `A1`, you could put in `A2` this formula `=A1+4`

Comment: "I need to calculate the nearest future date, that is a multiple of four days from the original Due Date" is a clearer way to phrase your question, in my opinion. Glad Scott was able to figure out what you meant!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this formula:

```
=A2+4*(INT((TODAY()-A2)/4)+1)
```

[image]

Comment: Bless you.  I believe this is the perfect answer.  Will be clicking as the correct answer as soon as I can.

Comment: If OP likes this, then great, but Scott, can you explain how you got here from the original question, which seems to be looking for `A2+4`, or maybe `if(A2 < TODAY(), TODAY()+4, A2+4)`?

Comment: @Mako212 The OP wording was a little funky, but I believe he was saying that the due date (`A2`) has already been passed. So, a send date, `B2` is updated every four days. So that a letter is sent every four days past the due date, and the day to send the letter is automatically updated every four days as well.

Comment: @Mako212 the OP wants to return the next day that is a multiple of 4 from the original date **AND** greater than today.  The Op does not want 4 days from today.

Comment: That makes much more sense, thanks for the clarification!